# Heatsink for i4-PAC

Tags: solid-state-relay, heatsink

I'm using a [CPC1998J](https://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/CPC1998J.pdf/$file/CPC1998J.pdf) "i4-PAC" solid state relay in a project that needs to fit in a very slim enclosure (e.g. hopefully around 15mm thickness), and I'm having trouble identifying suitable heatsinks.

I have in mind something like this (designed for a smaller TO-220), but am open to other ideas.  Something easily sourceable in Canada would be helpful (e.g. Digikey or Amazon.ca).  Appreciate any suggestions, or help with more efficient ways to search (e.g. is there a standard package type that's similar to my part's dimensions?).

[image: TO-220 example]

Comment: How much power do you expect to be dissipated? What material enclosure do you want to use? How will you get the heat out of the enclosure? Are there any other size constraints other than <15mm thickness? A lot of questions I know, but it is impossible to give any advice without more information.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Typically under 2A through the relay, but I'd like to spec it to 4A continuous (~120V AC).  It will be in a small enclosure with no vents, roughly 120mm length x 80mm width x 15mm to 20mm height, at present aluminum but if possible might want to switch to plastic.  Let me know if any other info is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to use the aluminium enclosure as a heatsink instead of going Package->Heatsink->Air->Enclosure. Without any vents all the heat will need to be transferred to the enclosure eventually.

If you use the enclosure as heat-sink it comes down to proper and practical attachment of the package to the enclosure as well as safety considerations for electrical isolation between SSR and enclosure. There are thermal adhesive tapes and other thermal interface materials that could work. The thermal pad on the SSR appears to be electrically isolated which might make it easier regarding safety:
[image]

If you insist on using a dedicated heatsink, there are slightly larger clip-on heatsinks designed for to-247 and to-264 packages.

e.g. this one by Fischer ([FK 280 MI 247](https://www.fischerelektronik.de/web_fischer/en_GB/heatsinks/C02/Attachable%20heatsink/PG/FK280MI247O/search.xhtml)):

[image]

Or this one by Ohmite ([WA-T264-101E](https://www.ohmite.com/assets/docs/sink_w.pdf)):

[image]

Note they have thermal resistances of >> 10 K/W which will make your SSR run quite hot in the enclosure at 4A current. Thermal conduction to the enclosure should be preferred in my opinion.